# Horses or ATVS?

Tags: technology, transportation, vehicles, horses

Writing a setting where people have access to modern technology from the greater world, but the people of this land haven't really developed yet; there isn't a rail or road network connecting the various settlements. This has me wondering if ATVs or other land vehicles would be more effective and cost effective at moving cargo over uneven, unpaved terrain. Would an aspiring merchant family be better off sticking to beasts of burden until the highway gets built? To be clear this is an earth setting with human inhabitants.

Comment: Remember there's a strict policy of one question per post ^^. I know you can be unsure on what to pick and this creates many questions, but this will only add noise in the answers if you take them all at once. You could ask either the horse vs ATVs battle or (probably better) focus only on the specificities of ATVs as transport on difficult lands. It's your call :).

Comment: Also, a few things to note : horses and ATVs have different "maintenance" and "building" costs. This can play a huge role in your settlers's choice. Moreover, as far as I can read, nothing prevents using both of them and use each of their strength as needed :).

Comment: And finally, the game Death Stranding's gameplay is solely about transporting goods in hard to navigate lands, so it has made good thoughts on these issues. There are [motorbike](https://deathstranding.fandom.com/wiki/Reverse_trike) which almost act like ATVs, perhaps they can serve as a source of inspiration?

Comment: A related question is [Would ATV Cavalry be as effective as horse cavalry?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/239045/40609) For the record, there are places a horse can go an ATV can't go and places where an ATV would be superior. Horses can eat off the land but can succumb to disease while ATVs require the transport of fuel and can break down. In short, one isn't better than the other, they're both tools each with pros and cons. The only difference is circumstantial, which would make the question Too Story-Based (a literal reason to close).

Comment: Is there a reason to not build all the settlements on waterways and use boats? The savings of using water transport compared to land transport are so great that people fought wars over who would get the privilege of sailing an extra fifteen thousand kilometers around Africa instead of transporting goods about 250km from the Mediteranean to the Gulf of Suez, and that's *with a road*.

Comment: @gs actually, I was thinking water transport would be much more common overall. I mostly saw caravans as filling spaces in between river networks. I was also thinking about portage technological workarounds or more canals, but I suspect the upfront costs would be more for a centralized nation's budget, rather than individual merchants or a loose tribal confederacy.

Comment: "uneven unpaved terrain" could cover anything from dirt roads over rolling hills to crossing the alps in winter, can you narrow it down a bit more.  also only one question at a time please.

Comment: There was a similar question a while back, and I think my answer fits quite well for this too (TLDR: Machines > Horses in almost all cases): https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/239170/are-horses-better-than-rovers-on-a-habitable-planet-with-a-small-colony/239225#239225

Comment: I did not reopen this because there is still far too little given about the terrain and circumstances of the region. Horse needs grass, ATV needs gas. Horse needs veterinarians, ATV needs mechanics & factories making parts. Because both horse and ATV are the best answer depending on your setting, it’s not answerable.

Answer (score 5):

ATVs will not help your situation. ATVs are designed with a number of features that make them less than ideal cargo haulers. They tend to have poor suspension and their steering relies on the rider shifting their weight, so if hauling any significant amount of cargo, they'll tend to bounce and slide around. They're also not that powerful - they can go fast, but mainly by virtue of light weight, and their performance would suffer tremendously with any appreciable amount of cargo. They're also rather dangerous.

There *is* an offroad vehicle that might meet your specifications... well, there *was*. The [overland train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overland_train) was a concept cooked up by the US Army in the 50s to haul military cargo over inhospitable terrain (especially in the Arctic). Huge tires, high ground clearance, and independent turbine-electric engines for each car made it capable of covering pretty much any kind of surface you could ask for. But by 1960 it was obsolete; heavy-lift helicopters did the same job but faster and better.

Why did the overland train disappear? After all, there are tons of inhospitable places where lots of cargo is moved that don't want to pay Army rates for helicopters. Some are serviced by railways but far from all. Australia, for instance, has vast amounts of Outback covered in gigantic cattle stations with little rail coverage and tremendous transport needs (and you don't know transport needs until someone's asked you to haul 100 head of cattle 300 km across the desert).

So what do they use? [Road trains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_train), large vehicles essentially built out of normal semis and tractor-trailers temporarily connected together. As the name implies, these need roads, but they don't need to be *great* roads. Simple asphalt or packed dirt does fine, as the linked page's images can attest. If Australian ranchers, who haul more cargo over rough terrain than just about anybody else on earth, find it easier to build roads than to maintain offroad trains, you can be sure that your settlements will find the same. They don't need a sixteen-lane Autobahn where they can drive 100 kph in air-conditioned comfort, they just need something broad and flat enough to handle freight at better than a walking pace.

Comment: I don’t think these work very well. The overland train requires fairly flat terrain without much vegetation and the road train is for roads. From the question we would assume a variety of landmasses with little road and train network, so most is done through rough terrain. Trees, hills, some deserts and flat terrain, mountains.

Comment: An ATV can still haul far more than a horse can, Cargo ATV's are also a thing

Comment: @John Yes and no. Your average ATV is 30-50 horsepower, which suggests far greater cargo capacity, but they're also lightweight and their steering stinks. On a flat open road I have no argument with your statement. But the rougher the terrain, the less all that HP matters and the more a brain and four legs do.

Comment: @JBH there a large variety of ATV, some have very good steering and suspension, and the rougher the terrain the less a horse can also carry, can horses go places ATV cannot , yes, but for most of the places humans live ATV are far superior.

Comment: @John Unless I've misread the question, the OP isn't asking about where humans live. In fact, [real Life cannot be an overriding limitation on any question unless specifically requested](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8143/40609). The wide variety of ATVs might be irrelevant if fuel is hard to come by and store. It's tough to claim ATVs are far better than animals when there are no maintained roads and a horse can eat almost anywhere. Just a point.

Comment: Cadence, it might help if you identified your answer as a frame challenge. You make a very good point, but it's along the lines of "well, none of the solutions you're presenting make sense because of X, but it makes sense if you consider Y."

Comment: Instead of road train, you might want to consider overland train. Basically the same but it's intended to be used in rougher terrain. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overland_train

Comment: @JBH the OP's question is so vague that its impossible to say what constraints are there, I had hoed they would fill in some information but they don't fix it soon I will end up deleting my answer and voting to close.

Comment: I would love to hear more about why they stopped using the overland train. Especially for accessing dessert terrain, one would think a overland train would be orders of magnitude more efficient than a helicopter.

Comment: @JBH I am intrigued by "for most places humans live"; does this mean there are at least some places that people live where giving up on beasts of burden for ATVs wouldn't be viable?

Comment: @SurpriseDog If you have a lot of cargo you need to get across a desert on a recurring basis, by far the most practical approach is to break out some bulldozers and *make a road*, then bring up ordinary cargo trucks. For small one-time runs, helicopters' speed and operational range are hard to beat - you'd need a lot more overland trains to make sure you had one when and where you needed it.

Comment: @Coquí (a) It's your question. You didn't mention that we're dealing with humans, nor have you explained the context of your technology. If we're talking about, e.g., humans colonizing a world, horses are cheap, replaceable, and easy to maintain. ATVs require manufacture, parts, fuel, etc. Please avoid a technology dichotomy: high tech transport on a low tech world. If all we're dealing with is dirt roads, ATVs could be better. Uneven ground? Horses. (b) The side of a mountain is traversible by horses but not ATVs. Steeper mountains by mountain goats but not horses or ATVs.

Comment: @JHB was worried adding this to the scenario since I feel like it would just bring up a million other questions, but my story takes place in a much less colonized America. Might edit it in

Answer (score 4):

### ATV are far better than animals

first cargo designed ATV's are a thing commonly used by rural farmers. Non-recreational ATV's are often called UTV's Utility Task Vehicles. UTV's that can carry a ton or more is common, this is without a trailer, no horse can come close even oxen would have a hard time matching it without a something with wheels to pull. On anything but the roughest ground a UTV can out preform animals, but no one is taking trade routes through the roughest ground, humans take the easiest path available. People only travel through rugged roadless mountains to get to very remote locations which are not places good for trade, and no matter what you used you could not transport much. For the vast majority of terrains a UTV is far better, there is a reason we use machines and not animals today.

[image]

[image]

**Machines vs animals**
But the single biggest advantage is ATV's are machines. Machines don't get tired, if the break you can replace parts, and an can of gas takes up far *far* less space than the food and water needed for a an animal.

**Trucks**
If they have ATV's they have trucks, and trucks can carry even more. A bunch of trucks far out preforms animals, the only reason we don't use them much today is they can't compete with trains and ships. There is pretty much a smooth transition from light truck to heavy ATV's the only difference is largely semantic.

**Roads**
Also not having highways is not the same as not having roads, roads are ancient tech. The oldest paved road that still has the original surface is almost 5000 years old, and dirt roads predate farming. People are not moving large amounts of cargo without roads, horses and oxen can only carry large amounts by pulling wagons/carts which also need roads. For some historical comparison, when trucks first became popular most roads in the US were just dirt roads.

Comment: UTVs look awesome. I'll probably go with that. Probably doesn't make too much of a difference, but to clarify the point on roads, even the beast of burden were relatively recent introductions. Most of the people re-domesticated feral horses, so even the wheel might not have had that much use until recently. It's true the animal caravans would have left paths, though

Comment: @Coquí people walking create paths, the oldest known constructed roads predate the domestication of horses, and the oldest paved roads are from the same time as the domestication of horses.